# Docker is creating two networks instead of one

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

- Docker is not my strongest point so bear with me please.
- I'm using docker and docker-compose to create a local development environment for Magento2. (https://github.com/victortodoran/magento2-docker)
- I've created a custom network to allocate static IPs to container
- Excerpt from docker-compose.yml (https://github.com/victortodoran/magento2-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

  networks:
    www:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
- I'm starting my containers using docker-compose up -d
- The issue is that it's creating two networks **thesis_default** and **thesis_www**

  - **thesis_default** has an ever changing gateway. Each time I put the containers down and raise them up again the gateway changes now is at 172.30.0.1 and if re-raise them it will be at 172.31.0.1
  - **thesis_www** has no gateway

**Questions**

- Why is it creating two networks? How can I prevent this if possible. I'm expecting only **thesis_www** to be created and it to have the gateway 172.20.0.1
- Why does **thesis_www** not have a gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose creates a default network automatically. And run all the services in that network by default.

You can overwrite the default network by using

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

Comment: All is good, only one network is created, but it does not have a gateway :(

Comment: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
networks.default.ipam.config value Additional properties are not allowed ('gateway' was unexpected)

Answer (score 1):

What is the results of running 'docker network inspect thesis_default' ? The now single network of 'thesis_default' should have a gateway since it is of type 'bridge'.

"...bridge - An automatically generated network with a subnet and a gateway..." - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-and-manage-docker-networks/

Comment: victortodoran@EVO798L:~/work/thesis$ sudo docker network inspect thesis_default 
[
    {
        "Name": "thesis_default",
        "Id": "82a3ae026e59f4d7712bbb3108bff802cf46fb909914930f8302acf8ac5c4d1d",
        "Created": "2019-05-01T15:28:52.603704632+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        }, ...

Comment: Oops. bit to long for the comments section. I'll try to run your docker-compose.yml this evening and see what happens on my end.